# Binding the same renderbuffer to multiple FBOs

Tags: opengl, rendering, opengl-es-2.0

My opengl scene has two passes - one which renders the entire scene (color and depth) and a second which renders only some scene objects, which needs the depth buffer from the first pass.

Is it possible to use two framebuffer objects FBO1 and FBO2, and to bind the same depth renderbuffer to both of them? A pseudo-code for that would be:

```
// ---------- Initialization ---------- 
// create 'FBO1'
// create render buffer 'RB'
// bind RB to FBO1
// bind TEXTURE1 to FBO1 for color rendering

// create FBO2
// bind RB to FBO2
// bind TEXTURE2 to FBO2 for color rendering

// ---------- Rendering frame---------- 
// bind FBO1
// render entire scene with depth writing enabled
// bind FB2
// render some objects again with depth mask GL_EQUAL
```

The result should be that TEXTURE2 contains only those parts of the objects which are not occluded by other objects rendered in the first pass.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible to use two framebuffer objects FBO1 and FBO2, and to bind the same depth renderbuffer to both of them?

Yes this is perfectly possible. However a single render buffer or texture must not be a render target in several attachments in a given FBO at the same time.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Of course. I edited my answer to make this clear(er).

Comment: so can I use one of the FBOs to read the depth buffer while I use the other as the render target and write to it?